# env not working in FreeBSD cronjob

Tags: scripting, cron, freebsd, shell-scripting

On my FreeBSD server, I have setup a cron script for backups using Duplicity. This script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

export PASSPHRASE=
export FTP_PASSWORD=

keyid=
remote=
excludelist=

/usr/local/bin/duplicity --volsize 1000 --max-blocksize=20480 --asynchronous-upload --full-if-older-than 1M --encrypt-key "$keyid" --exclude-filelist "$excludelist" /Data "$remote"

/usr/local/bin/duplicity --force remove-all-but-n-full 1 "$remote"

unset FTP_PASSWORD
unset PASSPHRASE
```

(sensitive data redacted, of course).

This script is located at /etc/periodic/daily/duplicity and works fine if I run it directly from the terminal. But it doesn't work when cron/periodic runs it, and that seems te be because `env` is not functioning correctly.

Initially, the hashbang of the script read `#!/usr/bin/env sh`, but that resulted in the error `env: sh: No such file or directory`. So I changed it to the direct path of sh.

The problem I'm currently having is that duplicity uses `env` internally. So currently, I get the error `env: python2: No such file or directory` when cron tries to run it.

Why doesn't `env` work inside cronjobs, and how can I fix this?

Comment: It may not be a matter of problems with `env` but rather the environment variables used when running the script. Try to add something like `env > /tmp/env.txt` inside the script run from crontab to debug what variables are available when running the script. `which python2` gives me `/usr/local/bin/python2` and `/usr/local/bin/` is specifically added to the `PATH` environment variable: `PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin` - notice `/usr/local/bin` in the last part. This may not be set up when you run the script from the crontab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Amiramix hinted, the problem was with the environment variables. More specifically, the value of `PATH`.

*/etc/crontab* contained the following line:

```
PATH=/etc:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
```

After I added `/usr/local/bin` to that, my script worked as expected.